# Some Flex properties not available in Flex 3.2 SDK

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, mxml

I recently added Flex SDK 3.2 to the list of compilers in my Flex Builder installation. (I know I am working with kind of outdated SDKs :( ).

Ok, so when I changed the SDK version to 3.2 for an existing project, I couldn't find the properties `buttonMode`, `useHandCursor`. And the `Filter` classes like `GlowFilter` and `DropShadowFilter` were not available. I was able to use them once I switched back to SDK 3.0.

Did I mess up something or where did those properties and Classes go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had similar issues when using Flex Builder 3. The only solution I could find was to add the playerglobal.swc to the build path. The SWC is located inside the SDK that you're using:

`Adobe Flex Builder 3/sdks/3.2.0/frameworks/libs/player/9/playerglobal.swc`

Of course if you're publishing for Flash 10, then use `player/10/playerglobal.swc`